# How can do release query interval in java

Tags: java, algorithm, release, intervals

I have two release version number. 
for example: 
oldVersion= 1.1.0
newVersion= 3.3.4

I want to create query in order to fetch other release version number
between oldVersion and newVersion like 1.2.1 or 1.2.5 or 1.2.5.1 or 1.3.0 but except 3.3.5 These version numbers must be returned as others release version (1.2.1 | 1.2.5 | 1.3.0 | 1.2.5.1 | 3.0)

Because these version number include is included range which oldVersion and newVersion

e.g:

oldVersion= 1.1.0
newVersion= 3.3.4

```
    1.1.0<1.2.1<3.3.4 format =(Major| Minor|Revision)

    1.1.0<1.2.5<3.3.4 format =(Major| Minor|Revision)

    1.1.0<1.2.5.1<3.3.4 format =(Major| Minor|Revision|Build Number)

    1.1.0<3.0<3.3.4 format =(Major|Minor)
```

e.g:

oldVersion= 1.1.0
newVersion= 3.2

```
    1.1.0<1.2.1<3.2 format =(Major| Minor|Revision)

    1.1.0<2.0<3.2 format =(Major| Minor|Revision)

    1.1.0<1.2.5.1<3.2 format =(Major| Minor|Revision|Build Number)

    1.1.0<3.0<3.2 format =(Major|Minor)
```

How can I use a method in java programming language as think version number as String type.

Especially this method must be supported all release version format as independent of number digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your string versions are not always in triple number format(they maybe "x.y" or "x.y.z.t.u.v....") then get each part in them and compare relatively.

```
boolean isGreater(String v1, String v2){
   int[]numbers1 = getNumbers(v1);
   int[]numbers2 = getNumbers(v2);
   for(int i=0;i<numbers1.length()&&i<numbers2.length();i++){
      if(numbers1[i]>numbers2[i]) return true; //v1 > v2
      if(numbers1[i]<numbers2[i]) return false; //v1 < v2
   }
   if(numbers1.length()==numbers2.length()) return false; they're same
   return numbers1.length()>numbers2.length();
}
```

What is the `getNumbers()` function, I think you can write it yourself, just use for loop and get all numbers that are separated by dots.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is work handle it. The problem  was easy after seing the solve. Thanks @Ta Quang Tu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string of versions are always in format "x.y.z" (no space, no other special characters except dots and digits).
Write a function to get relative value of a version, like this:

```
int valueOfVersion(String version){
   String numberStr = "";
   int numberInt = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<version.length();i++){
      if(version.charAt(i)=='.'){
         numberStr = "";
         numberInt*10+Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
      }
      else{
         numberStr+=Character.toString(version.charAt(i));
      }
   }
   numberInt*10+Integer.parseInt(numberStr); //process the last part of version
   return numberInt;
}
```

Once you have value of a version, you can use the value to compare the version with another version, greater value, greater version. Remaining is easy with you, I hope it's useful for you!

Comment: I am sorry I can not explain clearly my question. I updated question. Actually should be supported other release format "x.y" or "x.y.z.t" version. e.g:  1.1.0<3.0<3.3.4 or 1.1.0<1.2.5.1<3.3.4

Comment: @Yasin check out my new answer